# How I do use dynamic arrays inside nested structs?

Tags: c, struct, malloc

I have the following struct

```
#define MAXCHAR 80
#define MAXARRAY 200
#define MAXCELLS 15

struct structInfoNet  
{
    int idCell;
    char MacAddress[MAXCHAR];
    char Essid[MAXCHAR];
    char Mode[MAXCHAR];
    int Channel;
};

typedef struct structInfoNet Net;


struct structCell 
{
    int nPAS;   
    Net Red[MAXARRAY];  // How I do Convert this to a Dynamic Array ?
};

typedef struct structCell Cell;

int main()
{
    int numCelda;
    Cell cell[MAXCELLS];  // I do not care structure Cells being a fixed array
                          // But I want the nested structure inside Cells (Net) being a dynamic array  
}
```

I would like to use dynamic arrays, and convert the nested structure Net on a dynamic array that I can manage using malloc (and realloc to change the size), but I do not understand how to do it. Be aware that I do not need to change the main estructure (the outter structure Cell, that can remain as a normal array).   Is there a way to do such a thing ?
Thks!

Comment: What did you try?  What happened when you did?

Comment: You just call `malloc` as needed.  For example, to allocate space for 5 Nets in each element of the array, you can do `for( unsigned i = 0; i < MAXCELLS; i += 1 ){ cell[i].Red = malloc(5 * sizeof *cell->Red); }`

Comment: You can't have dynamic arrays inside a struct. Make it a pointer and use `malloc()` to allocate memory dynamically.

Comment: Another common technique is zero-length arrays: `struct Cell { int nPas; struct Net Red[0]; }` .  The additional space is allocated when you allocate the enclosing struct.

Comment: Note that my first comment assumes you have changed the declaration of the struct so it looks like `struct structCell { int nPAS; struct structInfoNet *Red; }`

Comment: @Barman,  that was my suspect (you can not have dynamic arrays inside a struc).  But I do not want to use pointers.

Comment: @WilliamPursell  Thks a lot !!   You comments were right, they solved my problem, I was now able to allocate the memory dinamically.   However, although the code rans, I got a "stack smashing" error on screen just before the program ends.  Any idea of the reason?

Comment: "stack smashing" sounds like you probably have some undefined behavior.  A likely candidate is that you are not allocating/freeing correctly.